# unity5 enemyDamage prob

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im having a problem from my enemyDamage script in unity5 when i play it and stick to the enemy i died instantly even the enemy damage is 10 and my health was 100

well this is my first time to make this things on unity hope you helps me :(

heres my code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class enemydmg : MonoBehaviour {


    public float damage;
    public float damagerate;
    public float pushbackforce;

    float nextdamage;

    bool playerInRange = false;

    GameObject theplayer;
    playerHealth theplayerhealth;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        nextdamage = Time.time;
        theplayer = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player");
        theplayerhealth = theplayer.GetComponent<playerHealth> ();


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (playerInRange)
            Attack ();
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other) 
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player") 
        {
            playerInRange = true;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit (Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player") 
        {
            playerInRange = false;
        }
    }
    void Attack()
    {
        if (nextdamage <= Time.time)
        {
            theplayerhealth.addDamage(damage);
            nextdamage = Time.time + damagerate;

            pushback (theplayer.transform);
        }
    }

    void pushback(Transform pushObject)
    {
        Vector3 pushDirection = new Vector3 (0, (pushObject.position.y - transform.position.y), 0).normalized;
        pushDirection *= pushbackforce;

        Rigidbody pushedRB = pushObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
        pushedRB.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        pushedRB.AddForce (pushDirection, ForceMode.Impulse);


    }
}
```

and this was my playerhealth

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playerHealth : MonoBehaviour {

    public  float fullhealth;
    float currentHealth;



    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        currentHealth = fullhealth;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public void  addDamage(float damage)
    {
        currentHealth -= damage;
        if (currentHealth <= 0) {
            makeDead ();


        }
    }

    public void makeDead()
        {

            Destroy (gameObject);
        }
    }
```

Comment: up i need more help :(

Comment: What is damage number? And damage rate number?

Comment: Right, the script looks ok, maybe your damage rate is just too short or st.

Answer (score 0):

```
theplayerhealth = theplayer.GetComponent<playerHealth> ();
```

I think this line of code fails you because the player is a GameObject. theplayerhealth is or should already be initialized in your other script. I think you could approach polymorphism  in a better way.

```
public class enemydmg : playerHealth{

}
```

This will allow you to directly inherit everything you need from the playerHealth script without having to grab extra components. You can also use this technique for may other scripts in the future.

Another approach that you could use is calling your class directly:

```
  playerHealth.addDamage(damage);
```

From now on when you name your scripts use capitalization. PlayerHealth, EnemyDamage, etc... That's just a pro-tip to make your code look a bit cleaner when you're doing things like this. (Optional)